# base.html in root template directory can't access "MEDIA_URL"

Tags: django, django-templates

[image]

This is the directory structure in my project.  For some strange reason, the base.html in my root template directory does not access {{MEDIA_URL}}, but the base.html(an identical copy) in my cart directory can access {{MEDIA_URL}}.

Another strange thing is:
i have this code in my base.html

```
            Hi there,
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                {{request.user.first_name}}
            {% else %}
                Stranger
            {% endif %}
            </br>
```

It never enters "{% if user.is_authenticated %}" in my template root directory, but it works perfectly with the base.html in my cart.

this is my settings.py

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/ec2-user/foodchute/foodchute/images'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `RequestContext(request)` in views.py and added `(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT }),` in urls.py

like https://github.com/halitalptekin/PyTr/tree/master/src/blog

Comment: hmm, i just had to add requestcontext to my views.py. i didn't have to do the r'^media thing, but thanks!